# Set Power BI datasource credentials using REST API, with longer-lived token

Tags: powerbi

I am able to use [this REST API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/update-datasource#oauth-2.0-credentials-example) to set datasource credentials in Power BI with an OAuth2 access token.  e.g.,

```
{
  "credentialDetails": {
    "credentialType": "OAuth2",
    "credentials": "{\"credentialData\":[{\"name\":\"accessToken\", \"value\":\"eyJ0....fwtQ\"}]}",
    "encryptedConnection": "Encrypted",
    "encryptionAlgorithm": "None",
    "privacyLevel": "None",
    "useEndUserOAuth2Credentials": "False"
  }
}
```

When I do this, the access token is short-lived and expires in an hour. After that, Power BI can no longer connect to the datasource.

What I don't understand is why when I log in to my datasource with the Power BI service through a browser, somehow the credential doesn't seem to expire; Power BI can still refresh the data hours later.

*My Question*: How can I use the REST API to replicate, programmatically, what happens when I provide my datasource credentials to the Power BI Service through my browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you configure connection interactively Power BI gets both an access token and a [refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens).

The API does not support doing that, but you can vote for the [idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=9f9b52f1-4428-ec11-b76a-281878bdb01d) to help prioritize the feature.

Comment: Already voted, thanks

Comment: So I take it the only workaround for automation, is to use username/password or long-lived personal access token / API key (e.g., Databricks)?

Comment: Or use an Azure Function  or Logic App with a Managed Identity to fetch a new access token and update the connection credentials on a schedule.